# can html5 do this- change color x to color y (floodfill) on image?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I dont have any html5 knowldge.

I need to do  a simple floodfill - change color x to color y on existing images.

Can HTML5 do that?
Could you provide an  example on how to do that?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine it would be possible but I'm not sure of anyone who has done it yet.  Here is an example of grayscaling an image.  I imagine a similar technique would work.

http://spyrestudios.com/html5-canvas-image-effects-black-white/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to draw that image on a `<canvas>` element first.

[Here's how to do a fill](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-shape-fill/) and [this tutorial](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/) describes how to load an image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is good example of flood fill in HTML5 https://github.com/Flower7C3/HTML5/blob/master/canvas_floodfill.js (this is my modification of Markus Ritberger script http://code.google.com/p/canvas-floodfill/downloads/detail?name=canvas_floodfill_v1.0.1.js&can=2&q=)